# Возможно ли заменить приложение уже существующим в Google Play и Apple AppStore?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, appstore

В Google Play и Apple AppStore имеются два приложения почти одинаковых, грубо говоря, разница лишь в иконке и названии.
От поддержки одного из них решено отказаться.

А - приложение которое останется
Б - приложение которое будет снято с публикации

Существует ли алгоритм, который позволяет заменить у пользователей приложение Б приложением А?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет.
Вы можете в приложении "Б", от которого отказываетесь, уведомить пользователей, что поддержка будет прекращена, но они могут использовать аналог "А".

Либо публиковать одно приложение "А" под разными именами "А" и "Б".